# Query Couchbase for missing document where no index exists

Tags: nosql, couchbase, sql++

I need to query a Couchbase collection for all documents that are missing a particular field.

e.g. `SELECT * FROM Bucket01 WHERE Field IS MISSING;`

However, I have some annoying limitations:

1. There is no index on the field.
2. There is no shared field between affected documents that does have an index.
3. I am not allowed to create any new indexes.
4. I do not know any DocKeys.
5. There is no primary index on the collection.

Can this be accomplished?  If so, how?

Comment: Those are some *very* annoying limitations. What version of Couchbase Server are you using?

Comment: @MatthewGroves 7.0.3

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you are not allowed to create any new indexes?

Comment: I suspect point 2 rules this out - but could you do a broader search that does hit an existing index and fetches a definite superset of your desired missing-field documents.  Then filter through them in code?

Comment: @dnault because people in charge are afraid of unintentional side-effects in the production database since it is a world-wide real-time application.  The query is temporary to find broken documents that need fixed, and is not something that will be needed long-term.

Comment: @GrahamPople unfortunately not, the only other shared field is also not indexed.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a one off via Eventing

```
function OnUpdate(doc, meta) {
    if (!doc.somefield) {
        // the field is missing, log it or write
        // the meta.id to another collection in KV.
        log("Missing somefield id", meta.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this idea.  If I understand correctly, the one potential downside is that this would only produce a result when an update takes place, and so any straggling documents that never get updated would also never be discovered, right?

Comment: @person0 If you deploy from Everything and leave the Eventing function running it will respond to all subsequent mutations that occur in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Given the restrictions you've supplied, this sounds very nearly impossible.

The eventing option in Jon's answer is probably your best bet, but given the restrictions, I'm going to guess they won't allow that either.

Another option (again, probably going to be restricted) is to use a [Couchbase (map/reduce) View](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/views/views-intro.html). These are deprecated in Couchbase 7, but still technically available.

The syntax would look similar to the eventing function:

```
function(doc, meta)
{
  if(!doc.someField) {
    emit(meta.id, [doc.foo, doc.bar, doc.baz]);
  }
}
```

Which would emit the ID of the documents that are missing, along with foo,bar,baz fields (if you need them).

**I must stress that creating Views are generally not a good option** when compared to SQL++, Eventing, K/V, etc. But if this is a one-off, temporary situation, then it might be okay.

Answer (score 1):

Given the restrictions you've supplied, this sounds very nearly impossible.

The eventing option in Jon's answer is probably your best bet, but given the restrictions, I'm going to guess they won't allow that either.

Another option (again, probably going to be restricted) is to use and query the [Analytics service](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/analytics/introduction.html). The Analytics service provides workload isolation, so that your queries would not affect the normal operations of your production workload.

This would require you adding at least one more node to the cluster with the Analytics service, [setting up a data link](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/analytics/manage-links.html), and then running your [SQL++ against that Analytics data set](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/analytics/1_intro.html).

Of course, if this is a temporary, one-off, then adding (and later removing) an Analytics node for a single query might be more trouble than it's worth. But since so many other paths have been closed off to you, it is an option.